# how to add new column to a csv file

Tags: excel, csv

I have a csv with a pipe (|) as separator, the file is composed with 600000 rows. I want to add a new variable "ACTIONSOCIALE" with a value of "N", here is the first line of the fil:

```
CDCOMPAGNIE|CDAPPLI|CDPRODUIT|ACTIONSOCIALE
14|13|533|N
```

How to do it authomatically in excell for the 600000 other line

Thx

Comment: [Edit] your post to show what you have researched / tried so far, and the problems you have encountered. See [ask]

Comment: One solution would be to open the file in Pyhton using pandas, please, let me know if you interested in this solution.

Comment: technically adding "|ACTIONSOCIALE" to the first line and "|N" to all other ones in a text file can be done very easy in as good as all languages... pls show your code and specify which part of your code isn't working as desired

Comment: thx I did it with notepad++